# Force secondary DNS server to resolve unresolved names

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-hosting, vyatta

Is there a way to setup on Linux (Vyatta in particular) secondary DNS server, which is used only to resolve requests, that were not resolved by primary DNS?

If I just set up secondary DNS, it is only used when primary server is down and not if primary server returns name not found.

Answer (score 1):

Based on further clarification from the below comment(s), my suggestion would be to set up a DNS server at your primary location as well, configure it to use your upstream public/ISP DNS server for its resolution, and configure conditional forwarding for your secondary locations domain to use the secondary location's DNS server.

If your secondary location used `sec.example.com` as it's domain, for example, all requests (`google.com`, etc) would go through your primary site DNS server to the public DNS, unless the lookups were for the `sec.example.com` domain. In that case, the request would be passed through to the secondary location DNS server for resolving.

Comment: The problem is, the primary server is public server and the secondary is supposed to be our internal server in different location, which should be used to resolve our network devices on that location. BUT, our server cannot be the primary, because it is located on different location to which we are connected via IPSec, and this would cause resolve delays. We could setup new DNS server on this location which would do what you said, but we don't want to add another server if possible.

Comment: @tikend I have adjusted my answer based on your additional information.